# Keyerror in time/Date Components of datetime - what to do?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, python-xarray

I am using a pandas DataFrame with datetime indexing. I know from the 
[Xarray documentation](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/time-series.html#datetime-components), that datetime indexing can be done as  `ds['date.year']` with ds being the DataArray of xarray, date the date index and years of the dates. Xarray points to [datetime components](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/index.html)  which again leads to [DateTimeIndex](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/indexing.html#datetimeindex), the latter being panda documentation. So I thought of doing the same with pandas, as I really like this feature.

However, it is not working for me. Here is what I did so far:

```
# Import required modules
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create DataFrame (name: df)
df=pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2017-04-01','2017-04-01',
                          '2017-04-02','2017-04-02'],
                 'Time': ['06:00:00','18:00:00',
                          '06:00:00','18:00:00'],
                 'Active': [True,False,False,True],
                 'Value': np.random.rand(4)})

# Combine str() information of Date and Time and format to datetime
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Time'],format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

# Make the combined data the index
df = df.set_index(df['Date'])

# Erase the rest, as it is not required anymore
df = df.drop(['Time','Date'], axis=1)

# Show me the first day
df['2017-04-01']
```

Ok, so this shows me only the first entries. So far, so good.
However

```
df['Date.year']
```

results in `KeyError: 'Date.year'`

I would expect an output like

```
array([2017,2017,2017,2017])
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

**EDIT:**

---

I have a workaround, which I am able to go on with, but I am still not satisfied, as this doesn't explain my question. I did not use a *pandas DataFrame*, but an *xarray Dataset* and now this works:

```
# Load modules
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

# Prepare time array
Date = ['2017-04-01','2017-04-01', '2017-04-02','2017-04-02']
Time = ['06:00:00','18:00:00', '06:00:00','18:00:00']
time = [Date[i] + ' ' + Time[i] for i in range(len(Date))]
time = pd.to_datetime(time,format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

# Create Dataset (name: ds)
ds=xr.Dataset({'time': time,
               'Active': [True,False,False,True],
               'Value': np.random.rand(4)})

ds['time.year']
```

which gives:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'year' (time: 4)>
array([2017, 2017, 2017, 2017])
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2017-04-01T06:00:00 ... 2017-04-02T18:00:00
```

Comment: try `list(df['Date'].dt.year)` this will return an array of the years.

Comment: oh as your date is your index (sorry missed that) try `df.index.year`

Answer (score 1):

Just in terms of what you're doing wrong, your are

a) trying to call an index as a series
b) chaning commands within a string `df['Date']` is a single column df['Date.year'] is a column called 'Date.year'

if you're datetime is the index, then use the `.year` or `dt.year` if it's a series.

```
df.index.year 
#or assuming your dtype is a proper datetime (your code indicates it is)
df.Date.dt.year
```

hope that helps bud.

Comment: Hi @datanovice. **Thanks** for your quick answer, I really appreciate it!

`df.index.year `
will yield
`Int64Index([2017, 2017, 2017, 2017], dtype='int64', name='Date')`

and

`df.Date.dt.year`
results in 
`AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Date'`. All of this is however still not what I want! Please look at the _xarray_ documentation. Please watch my edit.

Comment: Hey Gabriel, sorry Ive no experience with xarray from a quick nose at their docs, it looks like you need to pass the dataframe to an xarray, I can't see you doing that in your code?

Comment: Hi @datanovice. No, it works with xarray the way I updated my OP. Now the question would be, if the same works with pandas. I was assuming it does, but now I am not sure anymore :) 
Anyway, thanks for coming back to this again and helping!